# "opt" cannot appear in constant-expression

Tags: c++, switch-statement

In the following C++ program:

```
int opt;
in(opt);
switch(opt)
 case(opt == 1):
 //and so on…
```

where `in(opt);`is the procedure used to get the value of the integer opt.

I get the error here: `case(opt == 1):`

Basically the point is I want to make a way for the user to decide what feature of the program is going to be used. I also tried with a *char* but had no luck with it as well. I just can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: Instead of `case(opt == 1):`, try `case 1:`. Also, you need a curly brace after `switch(opt)` and at the end of the switch statement. Consider the examples here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

Comment: For learning basic C++ syntax such as this, it's better to follow a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) than to ask piecemeal SO questions.

Comment: @Blaze You don't necessarily need a `{` after `switch ( )`.

Comment: @Angew the program itself I would say it's rather complicated, it's weird I couldn't figure out this crap by myself :| Anyway thanks for the help

Comment: @melpomene I figured the `//and so on…` meant that there are going to be more cases than that, so I think a compound statement would help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `case` labels in a `switch` block need to be compile time evaluable constant expressions (and integral types).

Since `opt == 1` is only known at run-time, compilation of `case (opt == 1)` will fail.

Did you mean simply `case 1:`?

Answer (score 2):

```
switch(opt) {
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        break;
}
```

The `switch` part says that you're looking at the value of `opt`; each `case` statement gives a possible matching value. The value in a `case` statement has to be a compile-time constant.

Comment: Requesting permission to change "compile-time constant" to "compile-time evaluable constant expression"?

Comment: @Bathsheba -- that's too complicated for me. <g> Seriously: from a language-lawyer perspective that might be correct (I haven't paid attention lately), but for beginners it's just too many words.